# Will I keep the progress for my 3DS games if I delete my Nintendo Network ID?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

I recently wanted to go back to my 3DS after a while of not playing it. Though I found out my dumb self put wrong information for my NNID and Im not able to use anything like the eShop for example. I would delete it however I am afraid it would delete the save files for my games. (The Games are physical not digital)

Answer (score 1):

[According to Nintendo](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/337/~/do-nintendo-3ds-games-save-to-the-sd-card-%2F-microsd-card-%2F-system-memory%3F), game save data is saved directly to the **physical game cartridge**. So, deleting anything on your 3DS shouldn't affect the save data stored in the cartridges.

There seems to be some rare exceptions to this rule -- e.g. Super Mario Maker saving both to cartridge *and* SD card -- but you should be fine deleting your NNID without losing progress data :)

Note: [it looks like Pokébank is linked to your NNID](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/3ds/187276-pokemon-sun/answers/514197-if-you-delete-your-nintendo-network-id-will-the-save-data-on-your-cartrages-be), so you may lose any Pokémon you have in the Bank.